# Mathematical Induction Problem solving

Tags: proof-verification, induction, problem-solving

$1^3$ + $2^3$ + $2^3$ + ... + $n^3$ = ($1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)^2$

I start with $P(1)$ and get  $1 = 1$.

Then I do it with $P(n+1)$ and I get stuck.

$1^3$ + $2^3$ + $2^3$ + ... + $n^3$ + $(n+1)^3$ = ($1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n +(n+1))^2$

then I've tried substituting values and both ways and I cannot find anywhere to go with the problem.

$(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)^2 + (n+1)^3 = (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n +(n+1))^2$
                                 $OR$

$1^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + ... + n^3 + (n+1)^3 = (1^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + ... + n^3 +(n+1))^2$

I know that the sum of numbers in a row is $\cfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$. I'm not sure if that's of any use. I'm pretty sure there's a mathematical proof that I can't remember that'll clean up this problem so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $\sum_{i=1}^n i=n(n+1)/2$ is of use! You need to use it no matter which side you choose first. If we take the LHS first we have:

$$
\begin{split} 1^3+2^3+\dots +n^3+(n+1)^3 &= (1+2+\dots +n)^2+(n+1)^3 \\ &=\left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 + (n+1)^3 \\&= \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}+\frac{4(n+1)^3}{4} \\ &= \frac{(n+1)^2[n^2+4(n+1)]}{4} \\ &=\frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}{4} \\ &=\left( \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right)^2 \\ &= (1+2+\dots +n+(n+1))^2 = RHS \end{split}
$$

as required. I think starting with the RHS is slightly simpler.

Comment: I do not see why this was downvoted. It uses the additional fact that $\sum_{k=1}^n k = n(n+1)/2$, but my answer also uses it, though not as heavily.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2
=\sum_{k=1}^n k^3
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k\right)^2
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k+(n+1)\right)^2\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2+2(n+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\right)+(n+1)^2\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n k^3+2(n+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\right)+(n+1)^2
\qquad\text{(by the induction hypothesis)}\\
\end{array}
$

So,
we need to show that
$(n+1)^3
=2(n+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\right)+(n+1)^2
$,
because this will show
that the right side is
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^3
$.

Dividing by $n+1$,
this is
$(n+1)^2
=2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\right)+(n+1)
$,
or
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k
=\frac{(n+1)^2-(n+1)}{2}
=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$.

This you should know
or can easily prove
by induction.

Comment: Who is doing the downvoting? Why?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your proof. It complements my answer nicely as it shows how to prove from RHS. I think this way is easier in that you can 'see' where to go after using the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: I find it interesting that we started with different sides.